# How do I get the number of Followers gained and lost during a selected time range from Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to get number of Followers gained and lost or just the total followers during a selected time range.

For example:
if I send a request to: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/
I will get this Json:

```
{
    "data": 
    {
        "username": "kevin",
        "bio": "CEO & Co-founder of Instagram",
        "website": "",
        "profile_picture": "https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg",
        "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
        "counts":  {
            "media": 1419,
            "followed_by": 1138347,
            "follows": 643
    },
    "id": "3"
  }
```

But I can't get the "followed_by" for a select time range

I read the Instagram api documentation and I can't find anywhere a Endpoint to do a request that I want.

in MEDIA I can pass MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP as parameters, but I am not looking for medias, I am looking for the number of followers.

I know It's possible because there is a website https://minter.io that gets every information since the beginning of the account.

PS: I already have the Authentication with OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to do this, I think you have to keep a track of your follower count and update it every day. Setup a cron job to do this via API.

I just tried minter.io, I dont know how they show followers from day 1, I can definitely tell u it is `fake` and not accurate, I had about 1400 followers at some point and I removed them few months ago, so its back to 200 something, and minter.io does not show this at all. I think they just show a fake linear graph for historical data and going forward they keep a track of followers every day.

Comment: Or they may have developed their algorithms pretty well. Actually, I'm trying to figure it out too.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use the field 'followers_count' on the User node to get a starting point. This gives the total number of followers at the time of the request. From there you could calculate a running total by subtracting the daily follower count from the Insights api that you mention.

Get current follower count:
`curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v8/<user id>?fields=followers_count&access_token=EAACwX..."`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user

Get new followers for single day:
`curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v8/<user id>/insights?metric=follower_count&period=day&since=2020-10-5T07:00:01&until=2020-10-06T07:00:00`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights

Comment: Thanks! Glady the Instagram API evolved. It didn't have that at the time.

Comment: I think they are not returning the unfollows this way, so the count would be somewhat wrong needing further refinement

Comment: This is true, I don't see a way around that I'm afraid